# Published artifact patterns in Ivy

Tags: ant, ivy

When I resolve artifacts from my repository (e.g. filesystem), I use two artifact patterns:

```
<artifact pattern="${location}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
<artifact pattern="${location}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision]-[type]s.[ext]"/>
```

The first one is for jar files, and the second one is for sources or other types of artifacts.
I'd like to be able to publish artifacts the same way, but I don't know how.

Using just the patterns above, the publish task seems to consider only the first one, thus removing the type. If multiple artifacts have the same name and extension, they will be overwritten.

If I just use the second pattern, then for jar artifacts it makes ${artifact}-${revision}-jars.jar which is really ugly.

Finally, it seems to be possible to have optional parts in patterns, such as:

```
<artifact pattern="${location}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[type]s).[ext]"/>
```

But the -[type]s part is omitted only if the type is null or empty, and I'd like the type to remain "jar", in which case the part is not omitted.

So is there any other way?

Comment: @Flavio I added an answer

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `ivy.xml` files for artifacts? You should need to create `ivy.xml` and place them to your module folder, near `jar` files. `ivy.xml` example:

```
<ivy-module version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
    <info organisation="com.organisation" module="foo" revision="1.0"/>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="foo"/>
        <artifact name="foo-sources" type="source" ext="zip"/>
    </publications>
</ivy-module>
```

Then you should define ivy pattern in your resolver:

```
<ivy pattern="${location}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml"/>
```

Now if you use `<dependency org="com.organisation" name="foo" rev="1.0"/>` you will get all artifacts described in `ivy.xml`. There is a [way](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency-artifact.html) to select only the needed artifacts.

Comment: OF COURSE I use ivy.xml. I didn't mention it because I'm not having any problems with it, only with the artifacts. And dependencies have absolutely nothing to do with my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a solution, but a slightly better way is:

```
<artifact pattern="${location}/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same.
I found the solution, you can use:

```
   [artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
```

-classifier will be null/empty on the jar on sources/javadoc-jars it contains -sources/-javadoc.jar

I know its been a while, but I found this question by google. So for any future person it will be helpful I think.